# Not all points overlain on raster map are showing up with R

Tags: raster, r, point, overlay, sp

Using R, I loaded a raster file (.tif) and overlaid points on the map. I have 46 points but only about half of them appear on the map. I can't figure out why other points are not showing up. Here are the codes. I attached an image of all points and the R plotting results.

'db' (data fame) contains latitude and longitude in decimal degrees. The locations of those points actually showed up on the map are correct. And I can extract cell values of 'all points' from the raster file. It's just that the plot doesn't show all points in the data frame.

```
## Load points

sPoints=data.frame(
  x=as.numeric(db[1:46,4]),
  y=as.numeric(db[1:46,3])
)
samplingpoints=SpatialPoints(sPoints)

## Create SpatialPointsDataFrame

spFrame=data.frame(ID=1:46)
str(spFrame)

SamplingPointsTable=SpatialPointsDataFrame(samplingpoints, spFrame)

## Project points

proj4string(SamplingPointsTable) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
SamplingPointsTable <- spTransform(SamplingPointsTable,CRS("+proj=utm +zone=xx +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

## Plot sampling points on a map

plot(map.tif)
title(main="Map Title", sub="Sub Title",cex.main=0.8, cex.lab=0.8, cex.axis=0.8, cex.sub=0.8)
plot(SamplingPointsTable, add=T, pch=20, col=c("transparent", "black", size = 1))
```

Is this only because of scaling (points are too large for the R plot map)?

The projections of the map and the points are matching.

[image]

Comment: Without knowing what is in `db` at the start of this code I think we're stuck. What is the dimension of SampliingPointsTable? Does `coordinates(SamplingPointsTable)` look right? Is something going wrong with the `as.numeric` conversion from `db` at the start?

Comment: Hello, I added descriptions to the question. Hope you will re-open this post. Thank you.